# Multiplying and summarising values from two data frames R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have two data frames, df1 and df2, an example their structure is shown below:

df1:

```
   ID          A1     A2         A3        A4      A5
1   1 0.000000000 0.0000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.00000
2   2 0.000000000 0.0000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.00000
3   3 0.000000000 0.0000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.00000
4   4 0.001775742 0.0000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.00000
5   5 0.201775742 0.0000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.00000
6   6 0.000000000 0.0367 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.00000
7   7 0.000000000 0.0369 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.00000
8   8 0.000000000 0.0371 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.00000
9   9 0.000000000 0.0000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.00000
10 10 0.000000000 0.0000 0.01448181 0.0000000 0.00000
11 11 0.000000000 0.0000 0.01648181 0.0000000 0.00000
12 12 0.000000000 0.0000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.00000
13 13 0.000000000 0.0000 0.00000000 0.0012056 0.00000
14 14 0.000000000 0.0000 0.00000000 0.0012036 0.00000
15 15 0.000000000 0.0000 0.00000000 0.0012016 0.00000
16 16 0.000000000 0.0000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.00000
17 17 0.000000000 0.0000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.00000
18 18 0.000000000 0.0000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.04976
19 19 0.000000000 0.0000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.04978
```

df2:

```
   ID    C1     C2    C3
1   1 0.020 0.3540 0.258
2   2 0.030 0.3542 0.273
3   3 0.002 0.3544 0.288
4   4 0.022 0.3546 0.303
5   5 0.045 0.3548 0.318
6   6 0.046 0.3550 0.333
7   7 0.047 0.3552 0.348
8   8 0.048 0.3554 0.363
9   9 0.049 0.3556 0.378
10 10 0.050 0.3558 0.393
11 11 0.051 0.3560 0.408
12 12 0.052 0.3562 0.423
13 13 0.053 0.3564 0.438
14 14 0.054 0.3566 0.453
15 15 0.055 0.3568 0.468
16 16 0.056 0.3570 0.483
17 17 0.057 0.3572 0.498
18 18 0.058 0.3574 0.513
19 19 0.059 0.3576 0.528
```

I would like to be able to perform some calculations using both data frames, but unsure on how to accomplish this.

Firstly, I need to multiply column C1 in df2 with columns A1:A5 in df1, such that when there is a match on the ID in both data frames, there is a value for the multiplication, e.g., ID 4 and 5. The output would be something like this:

df3:

```
   ID        C1xA1     C1xA2       C1xA3       C1xA4      C1xA5
1   1 0.0000000000 0.0000000 0.000000000 0.00000e+00 0.00000000
2   2 0.0000000000 0.0000000 0.000000000 0.00000e+00 0.00000000
3   3 0.0000000000 0.0000000 0.000000000 0.00000e+00 0.00000000
4   4 0.0000390663 0.0000000 0.000000000 0.00000e+00 0.00000000
5   5 0.0090799080 0.0000000 0.000000000 0.00000e+00 0.00000000
6   6 0.0000000000 0.0016882 0.000000000 0.00000e+00 0.00000000
7   7 0.0000000000 0.0017343 0.000000000 0.00000e+00 0.00000000
8   8 0.0000000000 0.0017808 0.000000000 0.00000e+00 0.00000000
9   9 0.0000000000 0.0000000 0.000000000 0.00000e+00 0.00000000
10 10 0.0000000000 0.0000000 0.005152628 0.00000e+00 0.00000000
11 11 0.0000000000 0.0000000 0.005867524 0.00000e+00 0.00000000
12 12 0.0000000000 0.0000000 0.000000000 0.00000e+00 0.00000000
13 13 0.0000000000 0.0000000 0.000000000 6.38968e-05 0.00000000
14 14 0.0000000000 0.0000000 0.000000000 6.49944e-05 0.00000000
15 15 0.0000000000 0.0000000 0.000000000 6.60880e-05 0.00000000
16 16 0.0000000000 0.0000000 0.000000000 0.00000e+00 0.00000000
17 17 0.0000000000 0.0000000 0.000000000 0.00000e+00 0.00000000
18 18 0.0000000000 0.0000000 0.000000000 0.00000e+00 0.00288608
19 19 0.0000000000 0.0000000 0.000000000 0.00000e+00 0.00293702
```

Then, I need to sum each of the cols in df3, e.g., C1xA1, and then divide these by the sum of the ID col in df1 - leaving me with 5 values. I then need to apply the same method with columns C2 and C3 from df2. The output would be something like this:

df4:

```
  sum_C1xA.sum_A.ID sum_C2xA.sum_A.ID sum_C3xA.sum_A.ID
1       4.79946e-05       3.80104e-04       3.40541e-04
2       2.73858e-05       2.06951e-04       2.02787e-04
3       5.80008e-05       5.80008e-05       6.53470e-05
4       1.02621e-06       6.77690e-06       8.60859e-06
5       3.06479e-05       1.87292e-04       2.72688e-04
```

I do not need the output from df3, its only shown as an example of what I am trying to explain.

I have managed to compute this in excel, but this is becoming very repetitive and I cant work out how to implement this in R. Any help would be appreciated. Below is the structure of the data frames mentioned above.

```
df1<-structure(list(ID = 1:19,
                    A1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0.001775742, 0.201775742,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                    A2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0.0367, 0.0369, 0.0371, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                    A3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.01448181, 0.01648181,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                    A4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0.0012056, 0.0012036, 0.0012016, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                    A5 = c(0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.04976,0.04978)),
               class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -19L))

df2<-structure(list(ID = 1:19,
                    C1 = c(0.02, 0.03, 0.002, 0.022,0.045, 0.046, 0.047, 0.048, 0.049, 0.05, 0.051, 0.052, 0.053,0.054, 0.055, 0.056, 0.057, 0.058, 0.059),
                    C2 = c(0.354, 0.3542,0.3544, 0.3546, 0.3548, 0.355, 0.3552, 0.3554, 0.3556, 0.3558,0.356, 0.3562, 0.3564, 0.3566, 0.3568, 0.357, 0.3572, 0.3574,0.3576),
                    C3 = c(0.258, 0.273, 0.288, 0.303, 0.318, 0.333, 0.348,0.363, 0.378, 0.393, 0.408, 0.423, 0.438, 0.453, 0.468, 0.483,0.498, 0.513, 0.528)),
               class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-19L))

df3<-structure(list(ID = 1:19, C1xA1 = c(0, 0, 0, 3.90663e-05, 0.009079908,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                    C1xA2 = c(0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0.0016882, 0.0017343, 0.0017808, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0),
                    C1xA3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.005152628, 0.005867524,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                    C1xA4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 6.38968e-05, 6.49944e-05, 6.6088e-05, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                    C1xA5 = c(0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00288608, 0.00293702)),
               class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -19L))

df4<-structure(list(sum_C1xA.sum_A.ID = c(4.79946e-05, 2.73858e-05,5.80008e-05, 1.02621e-06, 3.06479e-05),
                    sum_C2xA.sum_A.ID = c(0.000380104,0.000206951, 5.80008e-05, 6.7769e-06, 0.000187292),
                    sum_C3xA.sum_A.ID = c(0.000340541,0.000202787, 6.5347e-05, 8.60859e-06, 0.000272688)),
               class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-5L))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively

```r
df1 %>% inner_join(df2, by='ID') %>% 
  summarise(sum=sum(ID),
            across(c(A1:A5), ~sum(.x*C1)/sum, .names = 'C1_{col}'),
            across(c(A1:A5), ~sum(.x*C2)/sum, .names = 'C2_{col}'),
            across(c(A1:A5), ~sum(.x*C3)/sum, .names = 'C3_{col}')) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('C'),names_to = 'name', values_to = 'value', values_transform = as.numeric) %>% 
  separate(col=name,into=c('C','A'),sep = '\\_') %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = A, names_from = C, values_from = value)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 5 × 4
  A             C1         C2         C3
  <chr>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1 A1    0.0000480  0.000380   0.000341  
2 A2    0.0000274  0.000207   0.000203  
3 A3    0.00000824 0.0000580  0.0000653 
4 A4    0.00000103 0.00000678 0.00000861
5 A5    0.0000306  0.000187   0.000273
```

Answer (score 2):

The process you are describing is matrix multiplication, and it can be done in R using `%*%`

For example:

```
A <- as.matrix(df1[,-1]) # remove the id
B <- as.matrix(df2[,-1]) # remove the id

t(A) %*% B
```

Which results in your desired output without the scaling by the constant factor.  The sum of 1:19 is 19*10, so your output can be done with this:

```
> t(A) %*% B/(19*10)

# Output
#              C1           C2           C3
# A1 4.799460e-05 3.801037e-04 3.405407e-04
# A2 2.738579e-05 2.069512e-04 2.027874e-04
# A3 8.235067e-06 5.800080e-05 6.534700e-05
# A4 1.026206e-06 6.776897e-06 8.608592e-06
# A5 3.064789e-05 1.872924e-04 2.726880e-04
```

Comment: Hi @brinypawn, Thank you! I was not aware of this. Can you explain what is going on when you do the sum of 1:19 and it becomes 19*10? How does this work to divide the sum of each of the df2 cols and divide by the sum of ID col if this has been removed? Would this method still work if the ID col in the df1 and df2 were not the same as the row numbers, e.g., ID=20:40

Comment: There's a formula for the sum of numbers 1+ 2 + 3 + ... + n: n*(n+1)/2 which I simplified to 19*10.  This formula actually has a very intuitive understanding if you look it up.  You could also use `sum(1:19)` (which is probably what I should have done to make more sense).  For your second question, I like to think of it as dividing the final output of `t(A) %*% B` by the sum of 1:19 instead of df2, aka `(t(A) %*% B)/sum(1:19)` , but it should be the same either way (you can factor constants outside of matrices).  If the ids don't correspond to the rows, then you could divide by `sum(df1$id)`

Comment: NOTE: If your ids don't correspond to each other, e.g., df1$id = 1,2,4,3 and df2$id = 1,2,3,4, then this method will not give you what you want, because you want to do this math on only matching ids, and matrix multiplication will assume that you already have the ids lined up.  In this case, you would have to line up the rows yourself, or use @jkatam's answer.  Also if you wanted to stick with excel, there is probably a matrix multiplication function you can use in excel